# How to get data from Teltonika FMB 640 GPS Tracking Device in Laravel? any clues?

Tags: jquery, laravel, server, serversocket

I am starting a project and the first step is to receive data from the Teltonika FMB 640 GPS Tracking Device. How can I do this in Laravel? Like how to configure the ports and all and then decode the data and store it in database?

Comment: Usually you would use a protocol server for this, like netty in java. Teltonika has a reltatively [good wiki](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Teltonika_Data_Sending_Protocols) where they explain their different protocols. Storing the data after decoding should be the simplest part. You can look at [traccar](https://www.traccar.org/), an open source gps server, how they decode and encode messages for the teltonika protocols.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can directly receive data in my laravel project without traccar or flespi?

Comment: google "teltonika php" #1 result [TeltonikaPHPDecoder](https://github.com/lbarrous/TeltonikaPHPDecoder). I dont now if its good, i dont know how it works but i guess you can build on that or other results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using core PHP and a package of https://github.com/lbarrous/TeltonikaPHPDecoder

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I will surely make a video and post a link here soon

Answer (score 0):

Check the flespi service (https://flespi.com/). If you point your Teltonika FMB640 to a dedicated IP:port in your account, it will parse messages into standard JSON format. Then you can either consume it via API (https://flespi.com/rest-api) or set up a stream to push the data to your server (e.g. https://flespi.com/kb/how-to-get-data-in-your-platform-via-flespi-http-stream).

BTW, they also have great support chat.

Comment: I've checked out flespi. Is there any way in which I can directly receive data in my laravel project without flespi

Comment: @ayzeecheema my suggestion was to use flespi to simplify data parsing and use the convenient API or stream to get data in Laravel. I don't know how to do that without flespi.